# Can I use "only" as adjective?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use only as adjective?

Is my following sentence correct?

> "My flatmate moved out on Sunday. After that I was the only person living in the property"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentences that I can see. (Aside for a missing comma after *after that*.) Do you have a specific concern about the use of *only*?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of

> **only**

is correct to describe you are the *solitary* person living there.